# using countsif to count items from rows if certain conditions in other columns match

Tags: excel

I'm trying to count instances where a value is present in column D only if certain values are present in either E,F, or G. Specifically, if an agent's extension is present in the column and there is a number 2 in any of the three columns in the row after it, it should count it. I started with this:

```
=COUNTIFS(D2:D392,"9123",E2:E392,"2",F2:F392,"2",G2:G392,"2")
```

But that only counts it if a 2 is the value for all three of the those columns in that row. If the value of one of the columns differs, I still want to include it in the count if a 2 is present in any of the others.

I tried this:

```
=COUNTIFS(D2:D392,"9124",E2:G391,"2")
```

With the hope that it would compare the entirety of the columns/rows from E to G, and if they have a 2 and it matches the extension in question it will count it. Instead it returns the #VALUE! error.

Any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT`, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D392=9123)*((E2:E392=2)+(F2:F392=2)+(G2:G392=2)>0))`

I didn't use quotes around 9123 or 2. `SUMPRODUCT` is more fussy than `COUNTIFS` - you only need the quotes if those values are stored as TEXT, otherwise it should work as written

Comment: I think that did the trick. If I'm understanding the formula right, it takes the number of times the extension is found in column D and multiplies it by the number of times the number 2 is found in any of the other three columns?

Comment: Almost - it won't count any row more than once even if there are 2 or 3 twos. Is it possible to have more than one 2 on the same row?

Comment: Yes it is, and yes it should not count that row more than once. This solution works perfectly. Thanks for the help!